# How do I store a collection of ObservableCollection<T> with different types for T?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, covariance, contravariance

I have a class `ActiveList<T>: ObservableCollection<T>` that I wish to store in a dictionary with key of `Type`, which is the `T` of `ActiveList`, something like:

```
Dictionary<Type, ActiveList<T>>
```

Of course the dictionary cannot be typed, as it should cater for different types for `T`. It may help if you know that `T` is constrained to `XTimeEntity`, so I could consider making the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Type, ActiveList<XTimeEntity>>
```

but how would I cast an `ActiveList<XtimeEntity>` to an `ActiveList<T>` when I want `Dictionary[T]`?

Comment: `ActiveList<XTimeEntity>` and `ActiveList<SomeOtherEntity>` are different. So you can't. All you  can do is use a common interface which is non generic or a generic one which is covariant.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I know I can't do exactly what I describe I want. That is the whole reason I'm asking this question. Could you perhaps please suggest a suitable covariant interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an Interface all ActiveLists share? Than you could have a `Dictionary<Type, IActiveList>`. But you would still have to cast the received value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use interface ?

Define an interface(IActive) to declare the method you want to realize, then implement it.

```
public class Acitve<T> : IActive
```

Add it to the `Dictionary<Type, IActive>`.

Comment: The closest I could come to IObservableCollection (untyped) is:

`public interface IActiveList : INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged`

as those are the two change notifications I derive from `ObservableCollection<T>` for.

Comment: Yes, I mean declaring the method you want to call outside, and you can do everything in the method.`public interface IActive { void Invoke(); }` If you inherit the class `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can also call methods belonging to the class.